# Imagej interoperability: convert new ImgPlus to old ImagePlus

Tags: imagej

I need to convert the new [`net.imglib2.img.Img`](https://javadoc.scijava.org/ImgLib2/net/imglib2/img/Img.html) to the old [`ij.ImagePlus`](https://imagej.nih.gov/ij/developer/api/ij/ImagePlus.html) class, because there is some old ImageJ 1.x I want to use.

[Supposedly](https://imagej.net/pipermail/imagej-devel/2014-April/002059.html), I can use [`ImageJFunctions.wrap()`](https://javadoc.scijava.org/ImgLib2/net/imglib2/img/display/imagej/ImageJFunctions.html),

```
static <T extends NumericType<T>> ij.ImagePlus net.imglib2.img.display.imagej.ImageJFunctions.wrap(RandomAccessibleInterval, String)
```

since `net.imglib2.img.Img` inherits from `RandomAccessibleInterval`.

The problem I am having is that I cannot import `ImageJFunctions`.

Code:

```
import net.imglib2.img.display.imagej.ImageJFunctions;
```

Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem:
ImageJFunctions cannot be resolved to a type
```

In my `pom.xml`, I am using `org.scijava` with `<version>26.0.0</version>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ImageJFunctions` lives in [the imglib2-ij repo](https://github.com/imglib/imglib2-ij), so you'll need to add this dependency to your pom:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.imglib2</groupId>
    <artifactId>imglib2-ij</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Edit:

You can leave the version empty if you're using [pom-scijava](https://github.com/scijava/pom-scijava) as a parent.

Mis-read part of your question, sorry.  You probably won't need the information below, but I'm leaving it for completeness anyway, hope that's ok.

If you havn't already, you may also need to [add the scijava maven repository](https://github.com/imglib/imglib2-ij/blob/master/pom.xml#L130-L136):

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>scijava.public</id>
        <url>https://maven.scijava.org/content/groups/public</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

You can check for available versions [here](https://maven.scijava.org/#nexus-search;quick~imglib2-ij), though it's often convenient to use [pom-scijava](https://github.com/scijava/pom-scijava) as a parent pom.

Comment: I am using the [plugin example tutorial](https://github.com/imagej/example-imagej-command). I thought it already contained all dependencies. Thank you very much for pointing that out!

Comment: The example-imagej-command only depends on "pure ImageJ2", without any ImageJ1-related parts. The net.imglib2:imglib2-ij component (along with net.imagej:imagej-legacy and net.imagej:ij) is one of the ImageJ1-related parts.